# how to read a line with an specific format) c++

Tags: c++

I am having problems reading from a `txt` file in c++.

The file is composed of lines, each line has a number of 4 digits that represents a year (e.g 1900) and movie titles separated by '#'.

the file's format is:
number#movie title#movie title#movie title

example of lines:

> 1900#Sherlock Holmes Baffled#The Enchanted Drawing
>
> 1904#The Impossible Voyage
>
> 1918#Stella Maris#Mickey#Shifting Sands#A Dog's Life#Shoulder Arms

I want to read each line, save the year in a `int` variable, and each movie title in an array of string. Please help.

Here is my (wrong) code:

```
istream& operator >>(istream &is, Cronologia &crono){

    FechaHistorica fh;
    int anio;
    while(!is.eof()){
        char  c[1024];
        char  aux[4];

        is.read(aux,4);
        is.ignore('#');
        anio = atoi(aux);
        fh.setAnio(anio);

        cout << "\n" << anio << endl;

        while(is.getline(c,1024,'#')){

            fh.aniadeEventoHistorico(c);

        }    
    }
    return is;    
}
```

FechaHistorica is composed by:
int n;
Array of string

Comment: [`while(!is.eof())` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: Read the entire line using [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) then use common [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques on that line.

Answer (score 0):

What about this kind of function:

```
string test="1918#Stella Maris#Mickey#Shifting Sands";
vector<string> buffer;

size_t found = 0;
while ( found <= test.size() ){
    found = test.find('#')
    buffer.push_back(test.substr(0, found) );
    test.erase(test.begin(), test.begin()+(found+1) );
}
```

It returns vector like buffer = [1918, Stella Maris, ....], and for the txt reading

```
ifstream f( path );
string line;

while (getline (f,line) ){
    // goes line by line, return line as string
}

f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `is.ignore('#');` is wrong. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/). So use as following

```
if (iss.peek() == '#') {
    iss.ignore();
}
```

And at the end `while(is.getline(c,1024,'#')){` will not end until the end of file. So I think, you read the whole line first and then process it like below.

```
string line;
while(getline(is, line)){

    istringstream iss(line);
    char  c[1024];
    char  aux[4];

    iss.read(aux,4);
    if (iss.peek() == '#') {
        iss.ignore();
    }
    anio = atoi(aux);
    fh.setAnio(anio);
    cout << "\n" << anio << endl;

    while(iss.getline(c,1024,'#')){
        cout << c << endl;
    }
}
```